# How to check button's color?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

```
if([button backgroundColor]==[UIColor yellowcolor]){
    [taggedBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

----------

if([button backgroundColor]==[UIColor yellowcolor])
```

How can I check button's color?

Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `[button.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor yellowColor]`

If you use `==` you compare the pointers. With `[UIColor yellowColor]` you create a new instance. And that one won't be the same as the backgroundColor of your button. ;-)

Sandro Meier

Comment: I guess it should be [button.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor yellowColor] and not isEqualTo

Comment: so how about checking title is it the same?

Comment: [button.title isEqual:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]]
something like this?

Comment: Yes it is same. You need to do if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"abc"]){  }

Comment: If you have set the text of button to @"" then there should'nt be any problem. But if you haven't set its text then its text is **nil** and not @"".

Comment: Then you won't compare the text as you have not set that. You need to set some text on the button. If you don't want to display any text and still want to compare it, you may set the text as @"" and then compare it as if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]){ }.

Comment: Then there must be some other issue. How are you setting text for button? What happens when you debug your application and control reaches that if condition?

Comment: [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat: @""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }

Comment: Wrong. It should be [button.titleLabel text] = @"".

Comment: for example this is working but when i delete 1 it is not working

[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString: @"1"]){
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CGColor` property of `UIColor`:

```
if (CGColorEqualToColor([button backgroundColor].CGColor, [UIColor yellowcolor].CGColor) {
```

Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html).